# Navbar Menu placement

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using a Bootstrap navbar and have customised it but when the responsive size moves to mobile the burger menu opens on the left side but I would like it on the right. Can anyone help?

http://stajniazkopyta.x10host.com/test.html

Html -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/navbar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Caveat">
    <title>Stajnia Z Zopyta</title>
    <style>body {background-color: black;}</style>
</head>
<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-none">
            <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                  </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

                  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                      <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                      </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item active nav-link-camps">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Camps</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item active nav-link-sales">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sales</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item active nav-link-gallery">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Gallery</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item active nav-link-contact">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                                    </li>
                    </ul>

                  </div>
            </nav>

        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>        
    </body>
</html>
```

Css -

```
.navbar{
    border-bottom: $lobster-yellow 3px solid;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the order of the `navbar-brand` and collapse button. In Bootstrap V4 for navbar, they have used `display: flex;` property. By using this content may align like a table-cell. When the device size below 768px, collapse menu gets visible, so the content aligns in order.

Another way is to apply `flex-direction: row-reverse;` to the `navbar` when it is below 768px using Media Queries. By this method, you are not needed to change the order from your code, which is in your question.

**My Suggestion**

My suggestion is to re-order the HTML lines as I give in the **Updated Code**. Because we don't need to add custom CSS to override the default Bootstrap framework.

**Your Code**

```
//Collapse Button

<button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>

//Nav brand
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
```

**Updated Code**

```
//Nav brand
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

//Collapse Button
<button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
```

**Image For Reference**

[image: I have changed the order of <code>button</code> and <code>a</code> tag]

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks for explaining